# Using qsort to sort a 2 dimensional array by columns from least to greatest

Tags: c, sorting, multidimensional-array, qsort

I am trying to use `qsort` to sort each column from least to greatest. as an example with an input of

```
 168.12.110.25
 64.113.134.35
 217.158.91.183
 102.130.129.146
 215.116.26.223
 81.162.78.0
 19.204.25.222
 245.124.138.157
 137.249.183.201
 106.61.236.67
 106.71.236.60
 106.81.240.63
 168.14.111.27
 168.17.111.27
 215.116.26.220
 137.249.111.202
 137.246.111.202
```

i would want an output similar to

```
19.204.25.222
64.113.134.35
.
.
.

106.61.236.67
106.71.236.60
.
.
.
137.246.111.202
137.246.111.202
```

I am trying to use a nested for loop to loop through each column and tell me if one column is greater than the next. and the code would go through each and let me now if it was greater than qsort would check and would move them accordingly.

I am wondering if I am using `qsort` correctly and if my code makes sense.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
//declare other functions/files to be used in the program
void print_fun(void);
void read_fun(void);
static int compare(const void *a, const void *b, int arg, unsigned char networks[arg][4]);
 
//read command line input and store the information
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //declar variable
    int arg = 0;
 
    //make argv into an int
    arg = atoi(argv[1]);
    //assign size to networks
    unsigned char networks[arg][4];
 
    //assign input to networks
    for (int j = 0; j < 1; ++j) {
        if (argc == 1) {
            printf("ERROR ERROR, you messed up\n");
        } else {
            // hold network addresses in a 2-d array, with 4 unsigned char
 
            for (int k = 0; k < arg; k++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    scanf("%hhu.", &networks[k][i]);
                    //checks to see if scanf was working properly
                    //printf(" %hhu", networks[k][i]);
                }
                //printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
 
 
static int compare(const void *a, const void *b, int arg, unsigned char networks[arg][4]) {
    const event *ae = a, *be = b;
    for (int i = 0; i < arg; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (ae->networks[i][j] < be->networks [i+1][j])
                return -1;
            else 
            if (ae->networks[i][j] > be->networks[i+1][j])
                return 1;
        }
 
        void qsort(void networks, size_t arg, size_t 4,
                   int(*compar)(const void*a, const void *b));
 
    }
}
```

Comment: The compare function fails to `return 0` when the two fields are equal (not all control paths return a value). But I don't understand how you are able to use a comparator function taking 4 arguments, when the `qsort` spec is for 2 (as you show in the unnecessary declaration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a comparison function like this:

```
#include <string.h>

int compare_quads(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return memcmp(a, b, 4);
}
```

and use it like this:

```
//read command line input and store the information
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //declare variable
    int arg = 0;
 
    //make argv into an int
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: %s <number>\n", argv[0]);
        return 2;
    }
    arg = atoi(argv[1]);
    //assign size to networks
    unsigned char networks[arg][4];
 
    //assign input to networks
    for (int k = 0; k < arg; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
             scanf("%hhu.", &networks[k][i]);
        }
    }
    qsort(networks, arg, sizeof(networks[0]), compare_quads);
    //print the networks
    for (int k = 0; k < arg; k++) {
        printf("%d.%d.%d.%d\n", networks[k][0], networks[k][1],
                                networks[k][2], networks[k][3]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the k on the qsort? when i try to run the code it comes up as undeclared? does it just need to be declared?

Comment: @Ivickt: sorry about that, it should be `arg` instead of `k`. The number of elements in the array.

Comment: would you be able to clarify what the compare_quads function does?

Comment: `compare_quads()` uses `memcmp()` to compare blocks of 4 bytes. It returns a negative number if the IP address pointed to by `a` is lower than that pointed to by `b`, `0` if they are equal, ie have the same 4 bytes, and a positive number otherwise. `memcmp()` works like `strcmp()` but compares a fixed number of bytes instead of stopping on the null terminator.

Comment: @Ivickt: you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.